# Prove that matrix $(I - P)$ is not invertible when each column sum in $P$ is exactly $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

*$P$ is $3\times 3$ matrix in which each element has value $]0,1[$. Sum of each column is exactly $1$. 
$I$ is $3\times 3$ identity matrix. 
Show that matrix $(I - P)$ is not invertible.*

This is probably quite basic but I need some help with it.

So $(I - P)$ is a singular matrix i.e. $\det(I - P) = 0$. So far I've kinda empirically come to assumption that $\det(I - P)$ is always $0$ when sum of each column in $P$ is exactly $1$. I still can't find out how to prove that.

The answer should not lie in eigenvalues since it hasn't been taught to us yet in the class. I got a hint that some of the elements in $P$ can be written somehow differently since we know that the column sum is exactly $1$. I tried to write rewrite the matrix $P$ as shown below in the image $1$, after which I combined the matrix $(I - P)$ and tried row operations to take it to row echelon form to prove that ${\rm rank}(I - P)$ isn't full, but I wasn't able to do that.

[image]

Please I need help with this one.

Comment: Consider the all-one vector.

Answer (score 5):

If the sum of each column is $1$, then the sum of each column of $I - P$ must be $0$. Such matrices are singular, as the (non-zero) vector $(1, 1, 1)$ must lie in the kernel.

Comment: Hello sir, how can we say the sum of each column om $(I-P)$ is zero? Please explain a bit.

Comment: The sum of each column of $I-P$ is the sum of the column in $I$, less the sum of the column in $P$...